# FCM default onMessage override?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, messaging

I have a small web app which receives FCM messages, have a service worker, handles background messages and all are well. The Service Worker will receive the messages and will post them back to the main page so they can be displayed on page. That is for the background messages.

My problem is with the foreground messages being handled by some default onMessage() which passes them as well to the main page as messages encapsulated in a big message. So, lets say, if I have defined my own onMessage() function in a .js or in the main page itself, this message will be called and then the default one as well, which causes the message to be handled twice.

Below is the message I am receiving:

[image: FCM Message posted by default onMessage()]

The code in the service worker is:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-messaging.js');


var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBoi6gB1BHKxFBt58JJ4phWiZr9BKJaphI",
    authDomain: "webmessaging-7bef1.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://webmessaging-7bef1.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "webmessaging-7bef1",
    storageBucket: "webmessaging-7bef1.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "649072625962"
};

// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in the
// messagingSenderId.
firebase.initializeApp({
    'messagingSenderId': '649072625962'
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {

    console.log('On notification click: ', event.notification.tag);

    // Android doesn't close the notification when you click on it
    // See: http://crbug.com/463146  
    event.notification.close();

    // This looks to see if the current is already open and  
    // focuses if it is  
    event.waitUntil(
        clients.matchAll({
            includeUncontrolled: true,
            type: "all"
        })
            .then(function (clientList) {
                console.log('Clients Count: ', clientList.length);

                for (var i = 0; i < clientList.length; i++) {
                    var client = clientList[i];
                    var clientUrl = client.url;

                    console.log('Client URL:', client.url);

                    if ((clientUrl.indexOf("localhost") != -1) && 'focus' in client)

                        return client.focus();
                }

                if (clients.openWindow) {
                    return clients.openWindow('https://deanhume.github.io/typography');
                }
            })
    );
});

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
    console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
    // Customize notification here
    const notificationTitle = payload.data.title;
    const notificationOptions = {
        body: payload.data.body,
        icon: '/fcm-logo.png'
    };

    clients.matchAll({
        includeUncontrolled: true,
        type: "all"
    })
        .then(function (clientList) {
            console.log('Clients Count: ', clientList.length);

            for (var i = 0; i < clientList.length; i++) {
                var client = clientList[i];
                var clientUrl = client.url;

                console.log('Client URL:', client.url);

                if ((clientUrl.indexOf("localhost") != -1) && 'focus' in client) {
                    // client.postMessage(payload.data);
                }
            }

        })

    return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
        notificationOptions);
});
```

If I remove my onMessage() handler, I will still get the message posted by the default onMessage() handler.

Please, advise.

Thanks...

[UPDATE]
After some thorough checkups, I have come to some conclusion that the issue appears to be in the fact that I have the following two functions which appear to be doing exactly the same thing by receiving messages sent to the page.

This one is is supposed to receive the messages when the page is in the foreground and having focus.

```
messaging.onMessage(function (payload) {
    console.log('Message received: ', payload);
    alert(payload.data.title);
    // Get the data passed by the message and display on the page...
    document.getElementById('Select1').innerHTML += "<option>" + payload.data.title + "</option>";

});
```

And this one is mean to be receiving the data passed by the service worker when the message is received while the page is at the background and not having focus.

```
// Listen to messages from service workers.
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    console.log("Got reply from service worker: ", event);

    // Get the data passed by the message and display on the page...
    document.getElementById('Select1').innerHTML += "<option>" + event.data.title + "</option>";
});
```

So, basically, I am listening to the messages via two handlers at the same place and at the same time which results in the messages being handled twice at the same time... 
Any advise how I can properly organize this code?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of notes:

1- You should not include config details in the service worker (as it resides on the client's end) and restrict it to the required:

```
firebase.initializeApp({
   'messagingSenderId': '649072625962'
});
```

2- messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler is only triggered in the case of the background.

3- messaging.onMessage() you don't define in the service worker but rather in a .js as you mentioned to handle the cases of the foreground scenarios and will be triggered **only** in that case (there is no default definition of it until you define it)

Comment: I totally agree with you regarding the handler functions. I don't have onMessage() in service worker. Yet, I still get the message handled when app is in foreground! Even if I delete the onMessage()!!!

Comment: App.js:30 or html:26? and what happens if you remove messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload)?

Comment: then I don't receive any messages at all.

Comment: OK reasonable, this means you should get onMessage triggered when on foreground only

Comment: ya, but it isn't! Something else is taking over!

Comment: search the whole code directory for messaging and see all subscriptions .. maybe something hidden somewhere :)